# Block timer if execution is not completed

Tags: vb.net, timer, windows-services

This is the class that handle my service:

```
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class Service
    Private _lastRun As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Private ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        log.Info("Service started.")

        Dim timer As New System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000)
        AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timer_Elapsed
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        If now.Minute > _lastRun.Minute Then
            Dim m As New Main()
            m.Main()
            m = Nothing
        End If
        _lastRun = now
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        log.Info("Service is stopped")
    End Sub
End Class
```

After one minute the `Main` method is executed. The running time of `Main` method is unpredictable. If the execution takes more than one minute another `Main` method is executed. I would inhibit this behaviour, so if `Main` method is still running a new instances of `Main` method must be forbidden. What can I do?

Comment: Set the AutoReset property to False so it fires only once.  Call Start() at the end of your Elapsed event handler to get it to fire again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your timer object to have scope inside the class:

```
private _timer As New System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000)
```

Then when the timer elapses, disable it until you have finished you Main method:

```
Private Sub timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    _timer.Enabled = False
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    If now.Minute > _lastRun.Minute Then
        Dim m As New Main()
        m.Main()
        m = Nothing
    End If
    _lastRun = now
    _timer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have reach a different (but similar) solution by myself. I have wrap the Main method call in a timer.stop()/timer.start(), and this solution do the job even if your solution looks like more elegant.